# Java Remote object being exported over being serialized

Tags: rmi

I was reading through Java RMI  book by Esmond Pitt where I came across :-

"If an exported object is serializable,it is still passed by reference.The fact that the object is exported takes precedence over the fact that it is serializable"

Could anyone elaborate and expound the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, at one level, they had to choose one or the other, I suppose. (I wasn't in that meeting :)

But if I have an exported remote object, it needs to serialize to its stub (that is, it needs to be passed by reference) otherwise, you'd never be able to use it as a server-like object.

Did that make sense? If you allowed it to be serialized, it might as well not be a remote object, as any time you attempted to pass it over a network, you would fail to send the stub (which is what you need if you want to make it remotely accessible) and would simply send a serialized copy. Ergo, it's not a remote object any more.

Of course, you might be asking "why can't I choose dynamically each time this happens". Well, in that case, how on earth would you manage the process without causing some horrible coupling between unrelated parts of your software?

That's my guess :)

Comment: You can 'sort-of' choose dynamically, via unexporting, but I don't realy see the point.

Answer (score 0):

Being exported *must* take precedence for serialization purposes over being serializable. Otherwise RMI wouldn't work. It would just become a mobile-agent protocol.

`UnicastRemoteObject,` for example, implements `Serializable` by virtue of extending `RemoteObject`, which is serializable. If your remote objects extend `UnicastRemoteObject,` as most do, they are auto-exported on construction, and automatically replaced by their stubs during serialization, as the section you're quoting from in my book describes.

If it didn't do that, in preference to serializing as itself, it wouldn't *be* a `UnicastRemoteObject,` it would be more of a mobile agent, as described in another chapter of the book.

It follows that if you want it serialized, you have to unexport it first.

I think I also mentioned in the book that some versions of Java will then export it at the receiver on arrival, so it becomes a callback. I was never able to make much sense of this feature. The receiver could always have exported it himself if that's what he wanted: I don't see why it was forced on him.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/implementing.html

I hope this link will be useful.

"The rules governing how arguments and return values are passed are as follows:
Remote objects are essentially passed by reference. A remote object reference is a stub, which is a client-side proxy that implements the complete set of remote interfaces that the remote object implements.
Local objects are passed by copy, using object serialization. By default, all fields are copied except fields that are marked static or transient. Default serialization behavior can be overridden on a class-by-class basis."

Explanation:
This means that, if an object is made available to all as a remote object then the sender will put the reference into the stream and send it (when sender needs to send the object). The receiver receives the reference to the original object.
If an object is serializable and being sent, the sender makes a copy of the object and send the copy, which is independent object after created.

Comment: That's a correct description of *what* happens, but it doesn't actually answer the question as to *why* passing by remote referece takes precedence over passing by serialized value copy, in situations where both can apply.